# aws attach ebs volume with chef in hvm virtualization

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, chef-infra

I have a Chef recipe that is trying to create and attach an EBS volume but keeps failing.  It has worked fine on all my previous AMI's w/ `paravirtual` virtualization type.  But when I try to switch and use `hvm` virtualization it fails and tell me the mount point is already in use.  But it doesn't appear that it is.

My recipe to create/attach the volume is replicated closely from this resource, where the author creates a single EBS volume.
http://clarkdave.net/2013/04/managing-ebs-volumes-with-chef/#creating-the-ebs-volumes

```
================================================================================
Error executing action `attach` on resource 'aws_ebs_volume[application_ebs_volume]'
================================================================================

Aws::EC2::Errors::InvalidParameterValue                                      
---------------------------------------                                      
Invalid value '/dev/sdb' for unixDevice. Attachment point /dev/sdb is already in use

Cookbook Trace:                                                              
---------------                                                              
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/aws/providers/ebs_volume.rb:212:in `attach_volume' 
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/aws/providers/ebs_volume.rb:70:in `block (2 levels) in class_from_file'
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/aws/providers/ebs_volume.rb:68:in `block in class_from_file'

Resource Declaration:                                                        
---------------------                                                        
# In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/company-aws/recipes/ebs.rb                    

 23: aws_ebs_volume "application_ebs_volume" do                              
 24:     aws_access_key aws['aws_access_key_id']                             
 25:     aws_secret_access_key aws['aws_secret_access_key']                  
 26:     description node['companyaws']['ebs']['name']                       
 27:     size node['companyaws']['ebs']['size']                              
 28:     device device_id.gsub('xvd', 'sd') #aws uses sdx instead of xvdx    
 29:     action [ :create, :attach ]                                         
 30: end                                                                     
 31:                                                                         

Compiled Resource:                                                           
------------------                                                           
# Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/company-aws/recipes/ebs.rb:23:in `from_file'

aws_ebs_volume("application_ebs_volume") do                                  
  action [:create, :attach]                                                  
  updated true                                                               
  retries 0                                                                  
  retry_delay 2                                                              
  default_guard_interpreter :default                                         
  declared_type :aws_ebs_volume                                              
  cookbook_name "company-aws"                                                
  recipe_name "ebs"                                                          
  aws_access_key "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"                                      
  aws_secret_access_key "YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY/YYYYYYYYYY"           
  description "chef-test"                                                    
  size 50                                                                    
  device "/dev/sdb"                                                          
  timeout 180                                                                
  volume_type "standard"                                                     
  piops 0                                                                    
end
```

I've tried to verify that the mount point doesn't exist

```
user@chef-test:~$ df -h                                                      
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on                             
/dev/xvda1      9.8G  1.2G  8.1G  13% /                                      
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup                         
udev            996M   12K  996M   1% /dev                                   
tmpfs           201M  340K  200M   1% /run                                   
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock                              
none           1001M     0 1001M   0% /run/shm                               
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user                              

user@chef-test:~$ cat /proc/partitions                                       
major minor  #blocks  name                                                   

 202        0   10485760 xvda                                                
 202        1   10474380 xvda1                                               

user@chef-test:~$ ls /dev/xvd*                                               
/dev/xvda  /dev/xvda1

user@chef-test:~$ cat /etc/fstab                                             
LABEL=cloudimg-rootfs   /    ext4   defaults,discard    0 0  

user@chef-test:~$ sudo mount                                                 
[sudo] password for user:                                                    
/dev/xvda1 on / type ext4 (rw,discard)                                       
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)                             
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)                            
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)                                       
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)                           
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)                                  
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)                            
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)                                    
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)            
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)               
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)           
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)                                
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)                                      
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
```

Comment: Just an idea: Different virtualisation type means different device names. I had issues with this: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/device_naming.html

Comment: good point - I think "technically"  I'm still safe, but I haven't read that doc before...looks like I might be outside of their recommended device name for my EBS volumes anyways....might be time to refactor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@adam_Ocsvari had the right approach. When I switched my device from mounting `/dev/sdb` to `/dev/sdf` everything worked right away.